# Add dependency in gradle but dont need to show in External libraries section Android studio

Tags: android

I have requirement from client that he wants developer to use one library in main project but dont need to show the developer the code of that particular library.As once we add dependency in gradle, we can see its source in External libraries section.
Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html), particularly at the `downloadSources` param. It should block gradle from downloading all dependencies' source codes. Not sure if you could set it easily to download all sources, but to ommit only one or two dependencies.